# CakePHP Model with $useTable = false still tries to connect to database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to develop an application that does not use a database, but that still has some models.

First problem: Cake look however for the configuration of the database (APP/Lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php, line 69), it tries to include the file Config/database.php.

If the file doesn't exist, I get 2 warnings. If it exists (even if it is completely empty) all ok. I want to clarify that this takes place even in the absence of models.

Second problem: if I try to use a model, I get the error:

```
Missing Datasource Configuration
Error: The datasource configuration default was not found in database.php.
```

This happens whether the Config/database.php file exists, whether the file is not present.

Finally, I specify that models (including the AppModel) have the property $useTable set to false, but it seems that it makes no difference.

But I have noticed that everything works correctly when in an application that uses a database there are only a few models that do not use it (but the app as a whole uses it).

I found [this](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Primordial/2012/01/19/cakephp_v2_without_a_database_fixed) which proposes a solution, which then is the solution that is found on the web.

But below, in the comments, I read that Lorenzo says:

> This does not make any sense at all, CakePHP 2.0 will not try to
>   perform any datbase connection unless you request it to do so

It seems to me that it has not, maybe CakePHP does not perform any query but still want a database is configured. Is that so? Or I missed something?

Thank you.

Comment: You did not share your code with us. especially the model which tries to access the database. I bet you forgot `public $useTable => false` there.

Comment: @mark thank you, but it seems you did not read my question carefully.

Comment: maybe you didnt set it properly. Thats why it is vital to post the code. Also note, that this could have been fixed in a later cake version. Please try your code with the current 2.3 master branch and confirm that this "issue" still exists there.

Comment: @mark, there'is no code to see. My application now works correctly without models and database, but the file Config/database.php must be present, even if empty. If there is not, I get 2 warnings.
If I create a model, completely empty and only with the property $useTable set to false, I get the error that the database is not configured. 
I'm using Cake 2.3.1, sorry for the wrong tag.

Comment: @mark, you can try this also with an empty app. You know the PagesController in your application you just downloaded?
Download Cake, set tmp/ as writable and open the homepage. Look down. You'll see that he still wants the database file.

Comment: @mark, next, create the PagesModel, enter the property $useTable to false and creates a method that does absolutely nothing.  

For example:

    <?php
    
    class PagesModel extends AppModel {
     public $useTable = false;
    
     public test() {
      return true;
     }
    }

Now call the method in the controller. You will see the error.

Comment: @MirkoPagliai I tried a similar setup; database.php present, but not configured. Model with useTable = false; and a single method `find()`, which returns "hello world". I can use this without any problem

Comment: @mark. Mmh, ok, maybe I'm wrong something else

Comment: @mark, Cake could not read the model file 'cause it is not readable and it called the method `__call()`.  

I was stupid not to see exactly Error Stack Trace, thank you too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Possible causes

CakePHP doesn't try to connect to the database until it is actually required, however;

- The app/Config/database.php file should **always** be present, even if you're not using a database. However, you don't have to 'configure' the various connections if you're not using them
- If your models use behaviors, it's possible that database-calls are made by the behavior, causing CakePHP to attempt to connect to the database
- Various methods inside the Model class will make connections to the database (e.g. requesting the 'schema' or 'columnType'.
- Non-existing Model-methods will be mapped to a magic `__call()` method; This method will first check if a Behavior is able to handle the call, and otherwise will make a call to the database. E.g. using `$this->Mymodel->doSomething()` will cause CakePHP to attempt to open a database connection and execute `doSomething` in the database.
- If a Model doesn't exist, **CakePHP will create one**, basically, it creates an instance of `Model`, ***using schema information from the database***, causing a connection to be opened.

*Example*

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    // This controller does not use a Model
    public $uses = false;

    public function index() {
        // CakePHP will construct a 'Post' model here
        $this->Post->find('something');
    }

}
```

#### Datasources, even if no *database* is used

Having said that. In most cases, it's best to have your models use a datasource; A datasource does *not* have to be a database, but may also be, for example, a [`Twitter Feed`](https://github.com/alairock/SimpleTwitter) or a static [`Array()`](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/master/models/datasources/array_source.php).

Having a datasource simplifies most tasks (e.g. you can just perform `find(....)` to get the data from your source, whether that is a database or not.

Comment: Thank you @thaJeztah.

Yeah, it's seems Cake needs always the Config/database.php file, even if it is empty. 
This can also be seen with an application completely empty.

My model is completely empty, no behaviors, no methods, nothing of nothing, just the propriety $useTable set to false.

So I need to use a fake datasources, as explained in the link I posted? So why Lorenzo says there is no need?

Comment: You don't have to use a fake datasource, as long as you don't make use of Methods that will try to connect to the database. *Or* use an actual data-source (as I suggested in the last paragraph). If you *do* get an error, the Error Stack Trace will show you *exactly* what Classes/methods were executed and you'll be able to find out what triggered CakePHP attempting to connect to the database. **I would _not_ use a dummy DataSource, as this will only _suppress_ the actual problem**; The problem (error) is that you're making use of some method that *expects* a datasource or database-connection

Comment: Ok, you're right. Cake could not read the model file 'cause it is not readable. Then, as you say, it called the method `__call()`.  

I was stupid not to see exactly Error Stack Trace, thank you.